# View an activity on button click

Tags: android, buttonclick

I want to show the details of a list item in another activity when clicks on a button.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it would be better if you would mention some details... as far as i can guess u want to use some data from a previous activity to show in another activity.. The method to do this is putExtras in intent.. e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, nxtActivityName.class);
intent.putExtra(name, value);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the target activity, u can retrieve the data in the `onCreate()` method by using `getIntent().getStringExtra(name);` and use it as desired..

And if you are using a list, its better you use a `ListActivity` and override the `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` for doing ur needful...

Answer (score 0):

Additional to this you have to add a onClickListener on your selected button